# MediaPlayer больше не работает

Tags: android

```
MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
```

Эту ошибку я постоянно получаю.
 Компилю в АПИ 24 и Java 1.8

```
if (sound.isChecked()) {
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                    try{
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/audio.mp3"));
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                break;
```

Код как видите нормальный. Уже все перепробовал

Еще после запуска. Хотя ничего не работает. Я жму на кнопку плай и получаю

```
Error (-19,0)
```

Если еще раз нажать, то будет стоп `Error (-38,0)`

Comment: Не могли бы перефразировать - что значит больше не работает?Он раньше работал?После каких действий он перестал работать?

Comment: @Asgard, Я же написал выше. После обновы. Компилю в АПИ 24 и Java 1.8

Comment: А когда работало какие версии были?

Comment: @xkor, Ну работало месяцев 3 назад. Когда в последний раз запускал.

Если не верите то создайте сами щяс. Скомпилируйте в АПИ 24. Не 19. А 24. И попробуйте.

Comment: Вы уверены что в лог больше ничего полезного не пишется?

Comment: Бывало работал с MediaPlayer, бывала точно такая же ошибка с теми же кодами и она явно не от версии API и Java. Но вот причину не вспомню, хотя как-то поправил погуглив.

Comment: @Kostya, Я уже все перепробовал. И на стеке искал ответы. Все бесполезно. Уже не знаю даже что делать.

Но самоге главное это то что я тестью на Genymotion и на Эмуляторе не запускается mp3 и wav....хз что сделать чтобы они открывались

Comment: Проблема решилась установкой кодеков на телефон. Всем спс. Оставлю тему вдруг понадобиться кому. Чтоб не мучился

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой кодеков на телефон. Всем спс. Оставлю тему вдруг понадобиться кому. Чтоб не мучился

Answer (score -1):

`API 24` находится в стадии `preview`, и вопросы о том, что в нем что-то не работает должны отвергаться *по умолчанию*, т. к. он пока еще не готов к использованию. Не пользуйтесь `API 24`, если вы ожидаете, что ваше приложение должно вообще работать.

Comment: вообще то на сколько я понимаю API 24 гдет месяц как [релизнулось](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2016/06/android-n-apis-are-now-final.html)

Comment: @xkor, в первом же абзаце по вашей ссылке написано, что выпущено **4th Developer Preview**. Это именно то, о чем я написал в ответе.

Comment: _4th Developer Preview **of Android N**_ и _including the Android N final SDK_, то бишь на сколько понимаю - API 24 релизнулось, сам андройд с имплементацией этого апи пока доступен в виде 4го дев превью. Короче API 24 в качестве целевого уже можно использовать в продакшене. Но соглашусь что хоть уже и можно, но нужно ли...